# How to modify date format via Google Apps Script to dddd, dd MMM yyyy

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I am generatinf a pdf file, using date mentionned in SpreadSheet.
Nevertheless, I am looking to change the date format, to be displayed as (french) :

```
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
Lundi, 09 septembre 2022
```

I tried some to work out the code, but it didn't succeed.

```
function CreateBulkPDFs() {
  const DocFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1JeQYnMoXCJTai0F8LUPCt3xRCINzbO97WNP38Ax-u-w");
  const DossTEMP = DriveApp.getFolderById("1h62bRQVhfBFsPU6lI1L2Xb7K6ANXrYuA");
  const EmplacementPDF = DriveApp.getFolderById("1P5xdUZQz0fGObAYWFqk3jgIpA1T1hTlO");
  const CurrentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ADMISSIBILITÉ  SÉLECTION");
  //const timeZone = AdsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();
  const DATE = CurrentSheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  //const DateString = Utilities.formatDate(DATE, timeZone, 'MMMM dd, yyyy Z');
  //console.log(Utilities.formatDate(DATE, 'America/New_York', 'MMMM dd, yyyy'));
  const FONCTION = CurrentSheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  const UNITE = CurrentSheet.getRange("N4").getValue();
  const ANCIENNETE = CurrentSheet.getRange("N5").getValue();
  //const AncString = Utilities.formatDate(ANCIENNETE, timeZone, 'MMMM dd, yyyy Z');
  var NomMatr = CurrentSheet.getRange("A8:N" + CurrentSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    NomMatr.forEach(([check, ...row], i) => {
      const NOM = row[3];
      const MATRICULE = row[5];
      if (check === true) {
      CreatePDF(DATE,NOM,MATRICULE,FONCTION,UNITE,ANCIENNETE,"Appel d'intérêt_Comblement titulaire 4.05_" + NOM,DocFile,DossTEMP,EmplacementPDF);
      try {
        CurrentSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 8)).uncheck();
      }catch(err) {
    } 
  } 
});
}
```

EDIT:

I Modified some lines:

```
  const DATE = CurrentSheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  const FormattedDATE = Utilities.formatDate(DATE, "GMT", "EEEEE, dd MMMM yyyy");
```

**Pattern Examples**

[image]

[Source](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html)

Comment: The solution: `const DATE = CurrentSheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  const FormattedDATE = Utilities.formatDate(DATE, "GMT", "EEEEE, dd MMMM yyyy");`